# Solving a differential equation in matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Let S be an SDP matrix.
I want to solve $X'(t) = S -X(t)^2$ with initial condition X(0), where X(t) is a matrix.
I have used some tricks associated with Ricatti equations to find a solution but I would like to have an elegant solution.
Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

See "solution in a simpler case" in (ftp://whisky.ill.fr/pub/lss/Ekater/siam/29875.pdf).

Comment: This is a classical change for Ricatti indeed but the expression you get by solving the second order equation is not naturally written in a very symmetric way.